# Select distinct id from a table with multiple inputs

Tags: sql-server, distinct

I have a `PersonId` with me in the `People` table.

Now i have assigned positions to these Person based on a table named `PositionId` and `PersonId`.
The structure of this table is as follows :-

```
CorporateTeam
PersonId    PositionId
1           1
2           2
2           3
```

So a person with PersonId 2 has multiple positions.

Now I have another table for `Skills` which is based on `PositionId`

So i want to retrieve **multiple** and **distinct** skills for a particular person based on PersonId.

Comment: please explain it. question not clear

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
create table Person (
    PersonId int
)

create table Position (
    PersionId int,
    PositionId int
)

create table Skill (
    PositionId int,
    SkillId int
)
GO

insert into Person values (1), (2)
insert into Position values (1, 1), (2, 2), (2, 3)
insert into Skill values (2, 1), (2, 2), (3, 3)
GO

select distinct s.SkillId
from Person p
inner join Position pos on p.PersonId = pos.PersionId
inner join Skill s on pos.PositionId = s.PositionId
where p.PersonId = 2
```